# CSS: first and last adjacent siblings of class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to accomplish this:

[image]

Elements with values should have a gray 'ribbon'. Elements with values have a class `selected`, elements without any value don't.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <span>.</span>
    <span>.</span>
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">3</span> <!-- Should be gray -->
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span>.</span>
    <span>.</span>
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span>.</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    ...
</div>
```

To accomplish the gray ribbon, I think I need these CSS rules:

1. All elements with class `selected` should have a gray background. Easy.
2. The first and last element of a set of adjacent elements with the class 'selected', should be rounded. Not so easy.

As far as I know, there is no CSS selector like `:first-of-class`. And still, it wouldn't be enough, because multiple 'ribbons' can exist on the same line. I need something like `:first-adjacent-sibling-of-class`.

Is there any way to accomplish this with pure CSS, or do I need JavaScript?

Comment: You can find the elemet with class whose previos sibling doesn't have this class: `:not(.selected) + .selected`, and vice versa.

Comment: you need to share some code before we can try to help you . an example or something that replicates your structure

Comment: Mr. T is right, we need to know how many parents there are, which children belong to which parents, the tags could be an important thing to know as well, you should probably know that code is required already at 2k+

Comment: Ok guys, sorry I thought it would be self-explanatory, but you're right. I adjusted the question

Comment: @fikkatra it's better to use jQuery. But if you want pure CSS,  I can suggest you a work around. but for that, you have to re-order your values to reverse order.?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn this works great for the first element of the ribbon, but not for the last, as there is no 'previous sibling' selector.

Comment: @fikkatra There is work around for the `previous sibling` selector check this Link - https://codepen.io/bscherer/pen/XMgpbb But you will have to change the order of values in your code. IF you still want i can create a snippet for you with your answer.

Comment: @JithinRajPR that would solve the last rounded item, but would break the first, wouldn't it?

Comment: @fikkatra That I can create the another work around `no issue`. if you still want we can do it.!

Comment: @JithinRajPR of course, any help is welcome!

Comment: @fikkatra sorry that didn't go well for me, that was a dead end but I have an another work around for you and it will not break your value or design in small devices also. I have posted my answer please do look at it ty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might help, I added a `not-selected` class and targeted the adjacent selected element

```css
.selected{
  background-color: #b7dafd;
}
span{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.not-selected+.selected{
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.selected+.not-selected:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 20px solid #b7dafd;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">3</span> <!-- Should be gray -->
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">3</span> <!-- Should be gray -->
    <span class="selected">2</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (left) -->
    <span class="selected">5</span> <!-- Should be gray & rounded (right) -->
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
    <span class="not-selected">.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: A great work around but sad to say that. If we use this in a responsive way. This will not be the solution - **Because the last curve of the `.selection` is made by using `.selected+.not-selected:before` so the style is with the `.not-selected:before` so if that element went to the next line on small screen then the curve will be on the next line not with the `.selected`.**

Comment: Yes @JithinRajPR but we can easily handle this scenario by wrapping the whole row in a div also handling this one scenario is lot better that adding a whole new library for these small requirements, eventually they'll be doing DOM manipulation to get this done.

Comment: We can avoid it by changing some of your methods, please check my answer and one more thing `wrapping the whole row in a div ` is not an option, if it is there several methods as a solution.ty

Comment: There are several ways we can address this problem, your solution is one of the way. Nice workaround btw. Thanks.

Comment: You are always welcome. Just shared my ideas that's all. just wanted to point out the issues nothing personal. I already supported your answer but up vote. good work.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be best solution for your ***QUESTION***

As i have used the style **`span.selected+span.selected:before`** itself so **your selection is safe and will not break to the next line**.

Try this and tell me if there is anything more.Ty. Cheers..

```css
div {
  display: inline-block
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  /* top: 0; */
  margin: 10px 0;
}

span.selected {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span.selected+span.selected:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

span.selected+span.not {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="selected">1</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span class="selected">3</span>
  <span class="selected">4</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span class="not">6</span>
  <span class="not">7</span>
  <span class="not">8</span>
  <span class="not">9</span>
  <span class="selected">10</span>
  <span class="selected">11</span>
  <span class="selected">12</span>
  <span class="selected">13</span>
  <span class="selected">14</span>
  <span class="selected">15</span>
  <span class="not">16</span>
  <span class="not">17</span>
  <span class="not">18</span>
  <span class="not">19</span>
  <span class="not">20</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Each `.selected` is a circle.
- All `.selected ~` siblings of the first `.selected` have negative margins and the left side at `border-radius:0`
- All `.selected` that follow a `:not(.selected) +` is a circle with a positive left margin.
- All `:not(.selected)` that follow a `.selected +` have a positive left margin
- **Lines do not break unless you specifically make it so with markup**

### Demo

```css
.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.selected {
  background: grey;
  height: 4ex;
  width: 4ch;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -4px;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected~.selected {
  margin: 0 -12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

*:not(.selected)+.selected {
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 -12px 0 12px
}

.selected+*:not(selected) {
  margin: 0 0 0 12px
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>.</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span class="selected">3</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span>.</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span>.</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span class="selected">3</span>

  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span class="selected">2</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
  <span class="selected">5</span>
</div>
<span class="selected">5</span>
```